# Vb.net - Centering Text inside my label!

Tags: vb.net, label, frame

I am trying to make my first program in vb.net 2010, and I have a question.

You know how when you have a button, the text centers itself within the frame of the button?
I have a label in my application, that displays a different text (through the label) everyday.

How can I limit the text area, like the frame in the button, and center the text in this text area?  Or if it's easier to use the button, how can I remove the frame?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the property `AutoSize` to false and set the `TextAlign` property to the center.